# vb.net I am trying to size a control (label, textbox, richtextbox) so that it is the smallest square that contains a given string

Tags: vb.net

I need to present arbitrary text, which might include line breaks, in a square control with word wrap such that the square is as small as possible but sufficiently large to display the text in its entirety.

This is the closest I've gotten so far:
Load the text into a temporary rich text box, Rich, with BorderStyle = none
I increment the value of size, width=height=size until Rich.ClientRectangle.Width = Rich.Width.

If I could now extract the visual lines one by one I would be done, as I could then save the original string with appropriate line breaks for later display.

Visual lines are not, of course, the same as Rich.Lines array.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What are "visual lines"?

Comment: Please show us the code that you have and let us know what is going wrong or missing with the code. We can help fix it then.

Comment: What’s wrong wit setting auto size to true on a label control?

Comment: I used the term "visual lines" to denote the lines one sees when looking at the control to emphasize the distinction between the lines one sees and the line array of the control.  Each line in the line array might be very long indeed.

Comment: Setting the autosize to true presents the challenge of knowing that the text overflows the capacity of the label.  If I could detect that the label has overflowed, or, in the case of a textbox that the text ends with ellipsis (...) I would be done.